# React Conditional Classname in my parent container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have the following case

```
return (
    <section {...getRootProps({className: 'MuiFileDropArea-dashed'})}>
        My content
    </section>
```

I want to put a conditional statement in the **section line** that when `files.length > 0` the `className` becomes `MuiFileDropArea-Nodashed`

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to accomplish this is a ternary operator with backticks. There are other ways, but this is the easiest/most simple for most people to read when seeing your code later on.

```js
return (
    <section {...getRootProps({className: `MuiFileDropArea-${files.length > 0 ? 'Nodashed' : 'dashed'}`})}>
        My content
    </section>
```

An alternative would be:

```js
return (
    <section {...getRootProps({className: files.length > 0 ? 'MuiFileDropArea-Nodashed' : 'MuiFileDropArea-dashed'})}>
        My content
    </section>
```